# display background image if scroll height is at least a certain value

Tags: html, css

I am displaying footer and header background images on pages using the css-background properties.

```
#bodyContent {
    background-image:url(../images/splash_footer_short.png);
    background-position: center bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Some of my pages however do not have enough content so my footer image overlaps over my header image. I have elected to simply not display the footer image where the scroll height of the page is not tall enough.

How can I provide a conditional so my footer image only appears when the scroll height is long enough?

[image]

Comment: You should look into min-height

Comment: would overflow-y:hidden; work for you to simply cut off the image instead of not showing what would clip, or will your image look weird then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a CSS media-query to handle this:

```
@media only screen and (max-height:500px) {
   #bodyContent { background-image:none; }
}
```

The code above is to say, "When the page is less than 500px, hide the footer block"

You will need to adjust your threshold to suit (I guessed 500px, but you can change this to suit your needs).

Also, the `footer` selector is a guess. You may need to use a class selector, etc, depending on how you have defined your HTML.

[This article](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-web-above-the-fold/#article-header-id-1) covers the idea of "vertical responsive" web design (which is what we're discussing here) in more detail

Comment: By footer i mean my background footer image which I have defined as a property of my page content. My understanding was this media query would look at the browser height rather than the scroll height?

Comment: The media query is based on the view port dimensions. Are you needing to control the visibility of the footer image, based on the document's height?

Answer (score 0):

You should add a `min-height` property equal to the height of the background image.

Answer (score 0):

just use media screen
so :

```
#footer{display:none}
@media screen and (min-height: X){
 #footer{display:block}
}
```